# How to update every object inside a JSON array with PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, sql-update

I am trying to make a query that updates all the objects inside the nested json array i.e update first_name of all the people named 'John' to some other name.

My JSON is something like this but with way more data ofc:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5eb21a9f779aac987b2584b2"
  },
  "name": "Bouchard Restaurant and Inn",
  "cuisine": "Australian",
  "stars": 0.2,
  "address": {
    "street": "1602 Bosup Terrace",
    "city": "Sibharze",
    "state": "CA",
    "zipcode": "21875"
  },
  "reviews": [
    {
      "person": {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "57d7a121fa937f710a7d486e"
        },
        "address": {
          "city": "Burgessborough",
          "street": "83248 Woods Extension",
          "zip": "47201"
        },
        "birthday": {
          "$date": "2011-03-17T11:21:36Z"
        },
        "email": "murillobrian@cox.net",
        "first_name": "Yvonne",
        "job": "Counselling psychologist",
        "last_name": "Pham"
      },
      "comment": "Aliquam est reiciendis alias neque ad.",
      "created_on": {
        "$date": "2017-12-09T20:49:00.35Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "person": {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "57d7a121fa937f710a7d486f"
        },
        "address": {
          "city": "Nicholsbury",
          "state": "Indiana",
          "street": "699 Ryan Branch Apt. 371",
          "zip": "52277"
        },
        "birthday": {
          "$date": "2015-11-25T17:26:40Z"
        },
        "email": "cindy93@gmail.com",
        "first_name": "Mary",
        "job": "Conservator, furniture",
        "last_name": "Nelson"
      },
      "comment": "Quis sed tenetur eius illo.",
      "created_on": {
        "$date": "2020-01-03T16:55:51.396Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "person": {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "57d7a121fa937f710a7d4870"
        },
        "address": {
          "city": "Crystalmouth",
          "street": "3924 Mosley Burg Suite 602",
          "zip": "14969"
        },
        "birthday": {
          "$date": "2015-04-07T19:10:04Z"
        },
        "email": "harrissummer@hotmail.com",
        "first_name": "Jenna",
        "job": "Engineer, land",
        "last_name": "Smith"
      },
      "comment": "Recusandae rem minus dolorum corporis corrupti rem placeat.",
      "created_on": {
        "$date": "2019-06-13T13:00:34.473Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "person": {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "57d7a121fa937f710a7d4871"
        },
        "address": {
          "city": "Lake Meaganton",
          "state": "Idaho",
          "street": "2831 Kevin Knolls",
          "zip": "10914-3394"
        },
        "birthday": {
          "$date": "2014-02-08T01:03:22Z"
        },
        "email": "ythompson@hotmail.com",
        "first_name": "Christopher",
        "job": "Investment banker, corporate",
        "last_name": "Franklin"
      },
      "comment": "Id provident eius natus quasi minima nobis.",
      "created_on": {
        "$date": "2016-01-05T02:15:06.933Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "person": {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "57d7a121fa937f710a7d4872"
        },
        "address": {
          "city": "Morganport",
          "state": "Vermont",
          "street": "9069 Bailey Ferry Suite 423",
          "zip": "99473"
        },
        "birthday": {
          "$date": "2015-12-19T18:27:42Z"
        },
        "email": "elizabeth35@mccarty.com",
        "first_name": "Elizabeth",
        "job": "Theatre stage manager",
        "last_name": "Herrera"
      },
      "comment": "Sit perferendis nostrum suscipit cumque mollitia.",
      "created_on": {
        "$date": "2016-09-27T15:47:22.458Z"
      }
    }
  ]}
```

I have a query that updates the first object in the array successfully:

```
UPDATE restaurants
SET info = jsonb_set(info::jsonb, '{reviews,0,person,first_name}', '"Vedat"', true)
WHERE info->'reviews'->0->'person'->>'first_name' = 'John';
```

However, trying make an update query that updates all objects within the array (reviews) seems to be almost impossible.

I tried something like this:

```
UPDATE restaurants r
SET info = (
   SELECT jsonb_agg(jsonb_set(rev::jsonb, '{first_name}', rev -> 'person' ->> 'first_name' = '"Vedat"', false))
   FROM   jsonb_array_elements(r.info::jsonb->'reviews') rev
    WHERE rev -> 'person' ->> 'first_name' = 'John'
   );
```

But it wasn't successful, it gives me errors like:

ERROR:  function jsonb_set(jsonb, unknown, boolean, boolean) does not exist

**UPDATE**

I came up with this query but it runs inifitely

```
with rev as (
    select id, generate_series(0, jsonb_array_length(info::jsonb->'reviews')-1) i
    from   restaurants
)
update restaurants r
   set info = jsonb_set(r.info::jsonb, 
                 array['reviews', rev.i::varchar, 'first_name'], 
                 '"Vedat"'::jsonb)
from   rev
where  r.info->'reviews'->rev.i-> 'person' ->> 'first_name' = 'John'
```

Comment: Which errors pop up? Do you really want to update the `first_name` property of 'all' objects to a constant ? What is the actual update you are planning ?

Comment: Edited: 

ERROR:  function jsonb_set(jsonb, unknown, boolean, boolean) does not exist
LINE 3:    SELECT jsonb_agg(jsonb_set(rev::jsonb, '{first_name}', re...

I want to update the first_name of all people named 'John' who submitted reviews to another name.

Answer (score 0):

The query gets a bit complicated but here is a solution, unless it matters that the order of elements in the `.reviews` array is not preserved:

```
update test_j
   set j = jsonb_set( -- Replace the '.reviews' array with a concatenation of two arrays,
                      -- one with the unchanged objects and one with the changed ones.
            j
          , '{reviews}'
          ,    jsonb_path_query_array( -- Extract the objects from the '.reviews' array
                                       -- that need _no_ updating.
                                       -- Uses the SQL/JSON Path Language. 
                   j
                 , '$.reviews[*] ? (@.person.first_name != "Jenna" && @.person.first_name != "Yvonne")'
               )
            || array_to_json(ARRAY( -- convert 'set of jsonb' to PostgreSQL array and back
                                    -- ( do not forget the cast from json to jsonb !)
                   select jsonb_set(  -- Update the json data
                              jsonb_path_query( -- Select the objects from the '.reviews' array
                                                -- that need updating
                                                -- (2 names chosen to demonstrate multiple updates 
                                                -- with the original sample data).
                                  j
                                , '$.reviews[*] ? (@.person.first_name == "Jenna" || @.person.first_name == "Yvonne")'
                              )
                            , '{person,first_name}'
                            , '"Vedat"'
                            , true
                          )
                     from test_j
               ))::jsonb
          , true
       )
     ;
```

Most likely there are more elegant and more efficient ways to get the job done but the code should get people started.

Online demo available [here (DB fiddle)](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gUZjtRTpHGgWDux8PVGK6U/3).

The relevant section of the PostgreSQL 12 docs can be found [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)

Comment: This is greatly appreciated, it indeed looks scary. I tried it and it is running infinitely, any clue on why that might happen? I have 100K rows of json

Comment: I reckoned this beast is a performance hog. Given the size of your data it might be a more viable approach to extract the `.person` objects as records and build a (temporary ?) table from them. The data would then be updated in the relational model to have a json representation constructed afterwards (or on-demand).

Comment: Hmmm I tried it with 1K rows, it runs successfully but for some reason, it updated all of the rows which is strange

Comment: I see what's going on. I actually needed Yvonne changed to Vedat for example not including a third name or anything like that. Looks like some of the condition is making the query run for all rows

Comment: You can always add a `where` clause to the update statement to limit the operation to certain records of the `restaurant` table.

Comment: Yeah but that's not the proper solution. This query adds 10 times more people then it actually has. 

I.E I tried to run the query by removing the second person, so I did it like this:

'$.reviews[*] ? (@.person.first_name != "John")' 

In my data there are 67 Johns, the data has 1K rows.

The query ends up with 67000 vedats, 10000 times more than it actually should. So the solution is close, but i need 1000 less then it actually does to get it correct. Do you have any idea why it adds 1000 more than there are?